# In Windows Media Center, is there a way to use both digital and analog audio simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-center, media

I have a PC in my living room (HTPC) running Windows 7 Media Center. It has a Gigabyte motherboard and I am using the embedded audio. I have the analog audio output to a SONY TV and digital output to a Yamaha soundbar. In the Control Panel I can set one output or the other to be the default device and it works fine but then I usually have to restart Media Center to have it detect the changes.

So questions:

1. Can I have the audio outputted to both devices simultaneously so I don't have to switch?
2. If not, is there an easier way to switch outputs (ideally from my remote)?
3. Is there a add-in soundcard that offers this option?

Answer (score 1):

I once used this application (You can try it for free):

```
http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm
```

"Virtual Audio Cable software allows you to transfer audio (wave) streams between applications and/or devices.

It creates a set of virtual audio devices named "Virtual Cables", each of them consists of a pair of the waveform input/output devices. Any application can send audio stream to an output side of a cable, and any other application can receive this stream from an input side. All transfers are made digitally, providing NO sound quality loss (a bitperfect streaming)."

Comment: I saw that site once before. The site didn't look that professional so I wasn't to sure about trying it out. Any experience using it with Win Media Center?

Comment: I used it with another software, it simply create an additional output device that "redirect" the audio stream to one (or more than one) phisycal device. Never tried with WMC

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup as yours, the different is I use Sony home theater. From my PC analog output to Sony TV and I use Optical cable from TV to my home theater. All sound from PC to TV 1st then to Home Theater. No switching whatsoever.

If I have optical output on my PC, I would directly plug it to Home Theater System.

You can also upgrade your GPU with HDMI port. Since HDMI carry sound also, you won't need another audio cable. I am currently with this setup. HDMI from GPU to TV and the home theater already connected to TV via HDMI(↔). Sound is better than analog.

Comment: It's an older TV with only DVI video inputs and analog audio inputs. I have HDMI on the motherboard but no where to send it to. Maybe I can use this as an excuse with the wife to upgrade the TV :).